# Cake php Pagination code like stack overflow site 1 2 .... 4 5 .....100(last)

Tags: cakephp, pagination

how to create pagination like stack overflow site  1 2 3 4 5 … 69377 next in cakephp.where to write and how to write code. please suggest complete code

Comment: Is your problem the *"like Stackoverflow"* part, or pagination in general?

Comment: "Plz send teh c0dez" doesn't really work well on SO. Just sayin' ...

Answer (score 3):

Read about pagination in the Cookbook:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html

There is a `numbers()` method in the PaginatorHelper. Read about it it in the API:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links

Comment: +1 Yes. It's fully documented in the manual. Do some reading.